# How to find the path in a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to work on creating a 2d array

where variable a is true otherwise false.

I know i have to use recursion but i'm not sure how to go about this

```
 var a = [[
          [0,0,0,0,0],
          [1,1,1,1,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,1,1,1,1],
          [0,0,0,0,0]
      ]]

function MazeSolver(maze) {

  this.maze = maze;

  this.traverse = function(column, row) {
  console.log(1, this.maze[0][column][row] )
    if(this.maze[0][column][row] == 2) {

        console.log('1dwffdf',this.maze[0][column][row]);
    } else if(this.maze[0][column][row] == 1) {
        console.log("At valid position (" + column + ", " + row + ")");
        this.maze[0][column][row] = 9;
        if(column < this.maze[0].length - 1) {
            this.traverse(column + 1, row);
        }
        if(row < this.maze[0][column].length - 1) {
            this.traverse(column, row + 1);
        }
        if(column > 0) {
            this.traverse(column - 1, row);
        }
        if(row > 0) {
            this.traverse(column, row - 1);
        }
    }
 };
};
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is your expected output supposed to be here?

Comment: No idea what you are asking about.

Comment: How does the 2d array you want to generate look like?

Comment: @amirouche I don't think he is trying to generate any array. I think that array `a` is supposed to be "maze" but what does he want to do with it, no idea. Finding a path? `1` is something like wall? But where is start and where is end position? First and last index of given array?

Comment: @Oen44 I quote the OP "I'm trying to work on creating a 2d array"

Comment: you might be correct tho

Comment: @amirouche Then there is question title. Confusing...

Comment: You will need to give us quite a bit more information if you would like an answer.  Is that array supposed to be a maze with a path from `[0, 0]` to `[4, 4]` that looks like `r-r-r-r-d-l-l-l-l-d-r-r-r-r`?  If not, what does your `MazeSolver` have to do with it?  And speaking of that, what in the world is `"1dwffdf"`?  We need something to go on.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Sorry, yeh 1 is like a block cell and 0 is a free space and I wanna create a path from the upper left corner to the lower right corner by walking on the free cells

Comment: @zfrisch Sorry, yeh 1 is like a block cell and 0 is a free space and I wanna create a path from the upper left corner to the lower right corner by walking on the free cells

Comment: @ConorByrne Okay, but I'm asking what you're output should be. What are you expecting to get out of this traversal function - as in, what is the output supposed to look like? you just want to console log each position that's valid?

Comment: There are easily available maze solving algorithms.  (Somewhere I have a whole book of them!)  But you haven't made it clear what output you want, not do I make much sense out of your function.

Comment: @zfrisch I'm trying to determine a valid path, if i was to pass in something like var b = [[[0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0]]] wouldn't be valid. The outcome is true or false

Comment: @ConorByrne look, update your question. Nowhere is any of this clear.

Answer (score 0):

This code will iterate through the maze and reduce the values to an array of objects containing each `col` and `row` of the correct path.

**Note** Array.prototype.flat is still experimental so the below may not be compatible.

```
let path = maze.reduce((acc, _,row)=> {
let validpath = _.reduce((acc,__,col)=> ((__)&&acc.push({col,row}), acc),[] );
  if(validpath.length > 0) acc.push(validpath);
return acc;
}, []).flat(0);
```

**Note** This version uses Array.prototype.concat which can be used in combination with the spread operator as a polyfill for Array.prototype.flat:

```
let path = [].concat(...maze.reduce((acc, _,row)=> {
let validpath = _.reduce((acc,__,col)=> ((__)&&acc.push({col,row}), acc),[] );
  if(validpath.length > 0) acc.push(validpath);
return acc;
}, []));
```

**Try it out:**

```js
 var a = [[
          [0,0,0,0,0],
          [1,1,1,1,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,1,1,1,1],
          [0,0,0,0,0]
      ]];
let maze = a[0];

let path = [].concat(...maze.reduce((acc, _,row)=> {
let validpath = _.reduce((acc,__,col)=> ((__)&&acc.push({col,row}), acc),[] );
  if(validpath.length > 0) acc.push(validpath);
return acc;
}, []));
console.log(path);
```

**Note**: Keep in mind that the `col` and `row` values are based on indices of the array, which begin at 0.